# Up/down hotkeys in Microsoft Terminal

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal

Microsoft [Terminal](https://github.com/Microsoft/Terminal) looks pretty good. There *must* be a hotkey to jump upward and downward, as you'd do with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd>/<kbd>PageDown</kbd> in gnome terminal, but I can't find it. (I can scroll with the mouse wheel, but that's all I've found.)

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Isn't it usually Shift+PgUp/PgDown?

Comment: Here (Terminal) Ctrl-Shift-PgUp and PgDn.  Try that

Comment: @DanielB yeah, thanks. I just typed that incorrectly. But the gnome terminal shortcut doesn't work in the Windows terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows Terminal, you can jump upward and downward **by page** with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd>, or **line by line** with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑ Up</kbd>/<kbd>↓ Down</kbd> .

To see the complete keyboard hotkeys list, go to *Settings* in Windows Terminal.

For more info, see the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/actions#scrollback-commands).

Comment: @JellicleCat If some settings are not in `settings.json`, they are using the defaults. You can see the default `settings.json` if you hold **ALT** while you click "Settings".

Comment: If something isn't working you might consider using the Preview version of [1.11](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal-preview/9n8g5rfz9xk3?rtc=1&activetab=pivot:overviewtab) as it as a great deal of improvements.  Windows Terminal Github page has more information.